# Textfield insdie UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a textfield and two buttons inside a tableview cell and when you click on the textfield, it opens up a pickerview to make a selection. What I want is that, the user should only be able to click on the textfield and the buttons, and not on the tableviewcell. I don't want the cell to be selectable, only the textfield and buttons to be selectable, how do I do that?

I have already tried cell.selectionType and cell.userinteractionenabled but they just make the whole cell unselectable, even the textfield inside it...so that's not what I want.

[screenshot of what tableviewcell looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZVdk.png)

Kindly help!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you *sure* you set `.selectionStyle = .none` in `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: Do you want *some* rows to be selectable, and other rows not? Or ***no*** rows selectable?

Comment: Yup, I have tried cell.selectionStyle = UITableviewCellSelectionStyleNone and it doesn't work. I'm using obejctive c, not swift

Comment: I have two sections in my tableview, and i want all cells in my first section to not be selectable, but only the buttons and textfield inside those cells to be selectable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}
```

then also implement `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    return  indexPath;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! I got it, I edited my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to check which section I am in and make the cell unselectable when I am in my first section. I appreciate your help!